# system ("clear") no funciona correctamente

Tags: c

Buen día, estoy creando un código en C que me permita obtener información sobre los productos que se han vendido en un día en una tienda.
Sucede que cuando el usuario ingresa una opción de Categoría inválida, el código limpia la pantalla y vuelve a pedir la información.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Standard input-output
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void mensaje_inicial() {

printf("\t\tEjercicio 4\n");
printf("\n");
//Obtencion de la informacion
printf("Los productos pertenecen a tres categorias:\n");
printf("Categoria A: 20.000 y 80.000\n");
printf("Categoria B: 8.000 y 50.000\n");
printf("Categoria C: 100.000 y 200.000\n");

printf("Nota: Para ingresar la categoria, debe elegir letras     mayusculas.\n");
printf("Ejemplo: A, B o C.");
printf("\n");
printf("Para ingresar el valor del articulo, no utilice ni puntos ni     comas.\n");
printf("Ejemplo: Si desea ingresar 100.000 pesos, ingrese: 100000");
printf("\n");
}
int main (){

int cantidad_vendida = 0;

mensaje_inicial();

//Obtencion de la cantidad de productos vendidos
printf("Ingrese la cantidad de productos vendidos en el dia: ");
scanf("%i", &cantidad_vendida);
printf("\n");

//Creacion de arrays para el almacenamiento de valores
//1. Nombres
char nombres[cantidad_vendida][100];
char nombre;

//2. Id de productos
char id_producto[cantidad_vendida][100];

//3. Categoria del productos
char categoria_producto[cantidad_vendida];
char categoria;

//4. Valor del producto
//int valor_producto[cantidad_vendida];
//float valor = 0.0;

//Obtencion del nombre del producto
for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_vendida; i++) {
  printf("\n");
  //Obtiene el nombre del producto
  printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto %i: ", i+1);
  scanf(" %s", &nombres[i]);

  //Obtiene el id del producto
  printf("Ingrese el id del producto %i: ", i+1);
  scanf(" %s", &id_producto[i]);

  //Obtiene la categoria del producto
  //getchar();
  bool verificacion = false;
  while(verificacion == false){
    printf("Ingrese la categoria del producto %i: ", i+1);
    scanf(" %c", &categoria);
    getchar();
    if ((categoria == 'A')||(categoria == 'B')||(categoria == 'C')) {
      verificacion = true;
    } else {
      system ("clear"); //Se usa clear porque cls no es portable
      mensaje_inicial();
      printf("\n");
      printf("No ha ingresado una categoria correcta.\n");
    }
  }
  categoria_producto[i]=categoria;
}

//IMPRESION DE TODA LA INFORMACION
for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_vendida; i++) {
  printf("ELEMENTO %i\n", i+1);
  printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombres[i]);
  printf("Id: %s\n", id_producto[i]);
  printf("Categoria: %c\n", categoria_producto[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Cuando la persona no ingresa una opción correcta, limpio la pantalla e imprimo el mensaje inicial nuevamente pero por algún motivo aún queda una línea de texto en la parte superior de la pantalla y no logro entender por qué ya que esa línea debió ser eliminada luego de haber ejecutado `system ("clear")` y antes de solicitar que ingrese una opción correcta nuevamente...

Vean la primera línea:

[image: Ver la primera línea]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Estás en Windows o en Linux?

Comment: En Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En algunos terminales podrás limpiar la pantalla ejecutando la siguiente instrucción:

```
printf("\033[H\033[J");
```

Puedes obtener más información sobre esta secuencia de control en el siguiente [enlace](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

Si no funciona, siempre puedes usar la librería `ncurses` para este menester.

Comment: Genial! Sí me funcionó. Ahora mi pregunta es: Esta secuencia es portable? Es decir, si alguien corre el código en Windows, funcionará?

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo no, no funcionará. Para tener una solución portable, usa ncurses. Por otro lado, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución. Un saludo